# SQUID Proxy on Linux VPS - No Logs

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

I know how to setup SQUID proxy on a Linux VPS. My question is, is there a way to edit it so it absolutely doesn't keep any connection logs at all? I have set proxies up and am decent in Linux. I had a friend ask me if I could set this up for him, but I really am not sure how to make it so it doesn't keep any logs at all.

I know it is possible, but not sure if you can with SQUID or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this in the squid.conf file:

```
access_log none
store_log none
```